# .Net Fluent Validation set execution order

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I need to set execution order for validation so that it stops validating after the first fail.

However [this is not available](https://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/352581&ei=X4eZU96xKaWxywPLn4CICg&usg=AFQjCNFziV9I1uQRffJnVtomCr1Tca9V1A&sig2=5PM0VQKHQqLLq_Eu2hNpHg&bvm=bv.68911936,d.bGQ&cad=rja), so i am wondering what other way to do this.

Normally i would have something like this:

```
public Constructor(){

    // Simple validation
    RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull().NotEmpty();

    // advanced validation
    // item must exist in database
    RuleFor(x => x.Id).Must(ExistsInDatabase);

    // item must exist in database previously
    // item must be some of the allowed names -- fetched from db
    RuleFor(x => x.Id).Must(BeAReferenceInSomeTable);

    private bool ExistsInDatabase(){}

    private bool BeAReferenceInSomeTable(){}

}
```

But with this BeAReferenceInSomeTable can be executed prior to ExistsInDatabase.
So BeAReferenceInSomeTable validation will throw exception when Id does not exist in table instead of validation failing because of ExistsInDatabase validation.

To solve this first that comes to mind is something like this:

```
public Constructor(){

    CascadeMode = FluentValidation.CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

    // simple validation stays the same
    ...

    // advanced validation
    RuleFor(x => x.Id)
        .Must(ExistsInDatabase)
        .Must(BeAReferenceInSomeTable)
        .When(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Id) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name)
        );  
}
```

But in this case how do i set a propper message for validation since message must be given prior to execution.

Comment: You can use `.WithMessage("your message");` to add a proper message for validation failures, and this works with chaining as well (which is what you are doing in your second example).

Comment: Yes but ExistsInDatabase should return: "Id does note exist in database"
and BeAReference should return: "Id is not referenced in some table".

With WithMessage it is only possible to pass a static predefined string.

But this is not good since I only want 1 message to be returned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public Constructor(){

    // Simple validation
    RuleFor(x => x.Id).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure).NotNull().WithMessage("Must not be null");

    RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Must not be empty");


    // advanced validation
    // item must exist in database
    RuleFor(x => x.Id).Must(ExistsInDatabase).WithMessage("Must exist in database");

    // item must exist in database previously
    // item must be some of the allowed names -- fetched from db
    RuleFor(x => x.Id).Must(BeAReferenceInSomeTable).WithMessage("Must not be referenced");

    private bool ExistsInDatabase(){}

    private bool BeAReferenceInSomeTable(){}
```

}

And chained for execution order:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Id).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
    .NotNull().WithMessage("Must not be null")
    .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Must not be empty")
    .Must(ExistsInDatabase).WithMessage("Must exist in database")
    .Must(BeAReferenceInSomeTable).WithMessage("Must not be referenced");
```

Comment: When you set Cascade mode in the first line it is used only for that chain. So using it without multiple condition doesnt have effect.
 The rest of the code brings me to the same issue that opened the topic. 
 WithMessage that you added will be render the right validation error but validation might not be executed in order.

Comment: Then use the chaining to achieve execution orders.

Comment: I extended your example do get what i need but this does redundant operations. Do you think there is a better way?
 I will mark your solution as the right one since it is close (but not quite) to what i need.
    RuleFor(x => x.Id).Must(ExistsInDatabase).WithMessage("Must exist in database").When(x => x.Id.NotNullOrEmpty())

    RuleFor(x => x.Id).Must(BeAReferenceInSomeTable).WithMessage("Must not be referenced").When(x => x.NotNullOrEmpty() && ExistsInDatabase(x));

Comment: What "redundant operations" are being carried out?

Comment: For validation BeAReferenceInSomeTable ExistsInDatabase is executed prior to validation.
For validation ExistsInDatabase the same method is executed again.

This is not an issue for this small test but it scales in bigger tests.

Comment: Thats it, it didnt even occur to me that you can add multiple messages like that (i assumed the last one would be used).

This is the answer i was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Just to complete the picture - another way of handling this is using [Dependent Rules](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html#dependent-rules).

Something like:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Id).Must(ExistsInDatabase).DependentRules(() => {
    RuleFor(x => x.Id).Must(BeAReferenceInSomeTable);
});
```